# Wire Library - just the first byte device address is being transmitted

Tags: arduino, i2c, arduino-c++

I am starting to study the Wire library (no previous Arduino Wire library experience), I read some info taken from [here](https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/communication/wire).
As you all know, this really simple example changes the value of a AD5171 digital potentiometer via I2C. Written by Nicholas Zambetti and Shawn Bonkowski, demonstrates use of the Wire library.

I just copied and reduced the code below a little from the example. I am an experienced assembler and C/C++ programmer and hardware developer/designer. Although several I2C devices like DS3231 RTC, etc. work fine using standard Arduino libraries, the mentioned example doesn't work for me in my working NANO board. What am I doing wrong?

This code should transmit:

1. first the I2C protocol device address - Start / 8 + 1bits
2. test instruction data byte
3. variable 1 test byte constantly incremented
4. I2C Stop condition

The only byte I can see in my oscilloscope is just the first one (please see picture below). The 2 data bytes are not being transmitted. If I reduce the transmission to just the step #2 instruction single data byte, the same result is shown.

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() 
{
  Wire.begin(); // join i2c bus (address optional for master)
}

byte val = 0;

void loop() 
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(44); // transmit to device #44 (0x2c)
  Wire.write(byte(0x55));     // sends instruction byte
  Wire.write(val++);          // sends potentiometer value byte
  Wire.endTransmission();     // stop transmitting
  delay(50);                  // some time delay for my oscilloscope
}
```

This is what this code produces:

[image: This is what this code produces]

Answer (score 0):

I see transferred data as `01011000 1`. I hope the is right decoded. Why you not zoom it more for better reading? It is hard see data levels on raising clock edges. This match to address 44, 0x2C . As you can also see that you get NACK on the end of address octet. So this means no device with transmitting address is on the bus.
You can get error code about sending process from `endTransmission` function as return int. Send this value to serial monitor.
Error codes you can see in  [arduino documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/wire/endtransmission/)

```
uint8_t err;
  err= Wire.endTransmission();     // stop transmitting and get status
```

You can also use sketch i2c_scanner from arduino Wire examples to discovery right address of your device.

Comment: The transferred data is OK (0x2C) but I tried to make an "open loop" test without a slave device on the bus, and you are right, the function waits for one. The NACK is indicating this and the transmission of further bytes is blocked. The Arduino documentation nothing says about blocking.

Comment: Yes documentation is brief, but description of the return values says *"2: received NACK on transmit of address."* In other way, it is open sw, you can easy open source code and look how it is work. For me is totally OK if after error, transmission is immediately stopped.

Comment: I agree with you Peter, it is OK to do so. But a good complete documentation could avoid having to read the source code. One of the purposes of a library is not having to navigate the internals of the code, unless the problem is so ambiguous that this could be necessary. Thank you.